# How to check whether the values in a sublist are also shown in another sublist?

Tags: python, list, tuples, match, list-comprehension

I got two lists that store the coordinate points of a line segment, which are shown below:

```
a = [[[(193, 256), (185, 257), (102, 225), (374, 350), (544, 419), (1279, 704), (377, 329)],
      [(374, 350), (1000, 719), (1050, 719), (1009, 697), (544, 419), (377, 329), (0, 122),
       (0, 151), (193, 256)]],
     []]
```

```
b = [[(0, 122), (0, 151), (193, 256), (374, 350), (544, 419), (1279, 704), (377, 329)],
     [(249, 0), (1279, 118), (1279, 100), (1226, 92), (439, 0)]]
```

Basically, `list a` contains two sublists. There are two lists in the first sublist while another is blank.

`list b` also contains two sublists. The first one would be some points shown in the first sublist of `list a`. Another one would be points that are not shown in `list a`

And I want to compare two lists and create a new list. The sublist of `list b` will compare to the sublist of `list a`. For example, the first sublist of `list b` compares to both lists in the first sublist of `list a`.

If there are common points, then split the lists in first sublist of `list a`. For example, (193, 256) appears in first sublist of `list b`, first and second list of sublist of `list a`. Then, these two lists should be counted as two individual list.

If there are no common points, then extract that list. For example, there are no common points when comparing second sublist of both `list a` and `list b` apparently. Then `[(249, 0), (1279, 118), (1279, 100), (1226, 92), (439, 0)]` can be extracted.

In short, the expected outcome would be as follow:

```
new_list = [[(193, 256), (185, 257), (102, 225), (374, 350), (544, 419), (1279, 704),
             (377, 329)],
            [(374, 350), (1000, 719), (1050, 719), (1009, 697), (544, 419), (377, 329),
             (0, 122), (0, 151), (193, 256)],
            [(249, 0), (1279, 118), (1279, 100), (1226, 92), (439, 0)]]
```

So, there are three different lists in one list.

Here is what I have typed. Hopes someone can help me. Thanks!

```
final_segments = []
for segments in list_a:
    for point, simple_point in zip(segments,list_b):
        check_points = any(simple_point in point)
......
```

Comment: In your example, there are item(s) in `b[0]` specifically `(193, 256)`, `(374, 350)`, `(544, 419)`, and `(377,329)` that appears **both** in `a[0][0]` and `a[0][1]`. What if none appears on both, so only in `a[0][0]` or only in `a[0][1]` but not in both?

Comment: In my case, these 4 points `(193, 256)`, `(374, 350)`, `(544, 419)`, and `(377,329)` must be appeared in both `a[0][0]` and `a[0][1]`. As they are the shared points in both line segments. Thanks~

Comment: I can't able to understand exactly what you need as your output. According to my understanding if a value in sublist of b is found in sublist of a, then that b sublist should be removed and other sublists in a and b should be given as output in another list. Am I right?